# MySQL connection in Logic app required an on premise gateway by default - why?

Tags: mysql, azure-logic-apps

I have an azure hosted MySQL data base and am now trying to use the MySQL connector in a logic app. Unfortunately the connector requires an on premise gateway as one of the mandatory requirements. I have read that I should disable SSL which is already the case. Any idea how I can make a connection to this DB?

Comment: Not sure what the exact question is , please elaborate on your exact  requirement

Comment: MySQL connector requires a On Premise Gateway in order to set up the connection in the logic app but the MySQL database is hosted in the same Azure platform as the Logic App i.e. NOT on premise. How can I make the connection?

Comment: Added the answer. Also please edit the original question with the one you asked in the comment

Answer (score 0):

MySql connector in logic app at this point allows you to connect to the on premises mysql  database through an on premises datagateway. You cannot directly connect to the mysql database hosted on azure.  The workaround for this is that you write an azure function which connects with the mysql databases  and call the azure function in your logic app.  The azure function can be a http triggered